# If a question shows that it is trying to solve an issue on an older version of WordPress can it be closed as too localized?

Tags: discussion, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should we close outdated, abandoned questions?](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/should-we-close-outdated-abandoned-questions)

I recently watched [Joel Spolsky - Cultural Anthropology of Stack Exchange](http://vimeo.com/37309773) and I picked up a couple of things.

> 1) StackExchange network is not here to service the question asker but those hundreds/thousands of users that have the same question and are looking for the answer.

This is why we have the `too localized` close reason. If it only helps the question asker and no one else then its not welcome here on SE.

> 2) Those asking questions about old versions or legacy code, those question are only likely to help them and no one else as generally people use the latest up-to-date version of code possible. These question should then be closed as too localized.

So if I come across a question on our network that is asking about help that is clearly for an older version of WordPress or Plugin, and given what I now know about above, would it be acceptable for me to close these questions as too localized?

Obviously I wouldn't close questions that had accepted answers with high view counts as these questions are obviously doing their job of helping the masses of users.